# Firefox Add-On Development - Add Item to Right Click on Tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I had an idea for an add on that would require me to add an item/menu-item to a tab when someone right clicks on it. How would I implement this? I have no Firefox Add-On experience and I just had an idea that is simple, yet I thought would be cool.

Comment: Have you ever programmed anything in javascript? Or what documentation have you already read?

Comment: Just trying to understand how to develop extensions by browsing Mozilla's docs. I do have experience in Javascript, although not much.

Comment: For Stackoverflow community to be able to help you, you must already have something. It is impossible to guide you through the entire process of add-on writing. Find some FF add-on writing tutorial, try it and get back with anything which doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Marki555 with browser extensions sometimes people dont know where to start, this is ok. Albert are you making a bootstrap addon? Or sdk addon?

Comment: I am making an SDK add on!

Comment: Oh with SDK im not familiar hopefully one of the sdk experts will swoop in here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.document.getElementById("tabContextMenu")` to manipulate tab's menu.

Here is [code](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/files/browse/211890/file/resources/newtabintabcontextmenu/lib/main.js#top) of [New Tab in Tab Context Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/new-tab-in-tab-context-menu/)

```
let _ = require("l10n").get;
let winUtils = require("window-utils");
let { isBrowser } = require("api-utils/window/utils");
var delegate = {
    onTrack: function (window) {
        if (isBrowser(window) ){
          let menu = window.document.getElementById("tabContextMenu");
          let newtab = window.document.createElementNS("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul","menuitem");
          newtab.setAttribute("id", "contexttab-newtab");
          newtab.setAttribute("label", _("newtab_string"));
          newtab.setAttribute("accesskey", _("newtabaccesskey_string"));
          newtab.setAttribute("oncommand", "BrowserOpenTab();");
          menu.insertBefore(newtab, menu.firstChild);
       } // End isBrowser
    }  // End ontrack
} // End delegate function

let tracker = new winUtils.WindowTracker(delegate);
```